# Coursera assignment 3 'Ranking hospitals by outcome in a state'

Tags: r

I'm using WIn7 64x Rstudio Version 3.3.2

The following function is assignment 3 solution in coursera that I have created by looking at other people's solution. 
I have 2 qeustions.

```
best <- function(state, outcome) {
  data<-read.csv('outcome-of-care-measures.csv',colClasses = 'character')
  frame<-as.data.frame(cbind(data[,2],
                       data[,7],
                       data[,11],
                       data[,17],
                       data[,23]),
                       stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  colnames(frame)<-c('hospital','state','heart attack','heart failure',
                     'pneumonia')
  if(!state %in% frame[,'state']){
        stop('invalid state')
        }
  else if(!outcome %in% c('hostpital','state','heart attack','heart failure',
                          'pneumonia')){
        stop('invalid outcome')
  }
  else{
        wh<-which(frame[,'state']==state)
        cr<-frame[wh,]
        num<-as.numeric(cr[,outcome])
        minval<-min(num, na.rm=TRUE)
        result<-cr[,'hospital'][which(num==minval)]
        output<-result[order(result)]
  }
  return(output)
  }
```

In this function, ***First*,** I don't know the use of "stringAsFactors=FALSE".

```
 frame<-as.data.frame(cbind(data[,2],
                   data[,7],
                   data[,11],
                   data[,17],
                   data[,23]),
                   **stringsAsFactors=FALSE**)
```

I've the read help document for 'stingAsFactors' via 'read.csv', I don't understand it.

When I remove this('stingAsFactors=FALSE' / functions's name is best2), the return is

> best2('SC','heart attack')

```
[1] MUSC MEDICAL CENTER
4510 Levels: ABBEVILLE AREA MEDICAL CENTER ABBEVILLE GENERAL HOSPITAL ... ZUNI COMPREHENSIVE COMMUNITY HEALTH CENTER
```

When I don't remove this, the return is

> best('SC','heart attack')

```
[1] "MUSC MEDICAL CENTER"
Warning message: In best("SC", "heart attack") : NAs introduced by coercion
```

***Second question*,**

```
result<-cr[,'hospital'][which(num==minval)]
```

Can the square bracket appear one after the other? In this case, Is the 'cr data' applied to the two square bracket?

I would be really grateful if you could tell about this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I'll try to be nice, but you shouldn't really be copying answers, especially if you don't understand it. But to answer your questions: First, `stringsAsFactors` as you can see sets how R treats strings in the .csv. When set to `FALSE` it treats them as characters and imports them that way. When set to `TRUE` (or not set at all), it treats them as factors. And that is why you see it displayed in levels. Second, the code is creating `result`, which is the `hospital` column of `cr` and only the data that fits the given condition of `num=minval`.

Comment: Thank you. I understand how to use 'stringsAsFactors'. 
I'll newly create a function for assignment on my own, not cheat. Thank you very much :)